# Why the doubly non-central F distribution does not have a mean or variance if the denominator degree of freedom is less than or equal 2 ??

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Normally the doubly non-central F distribution is generated by the division of two non-central chi squared Random Variables,, so what is the the problem of using any famous formula to get the mean of a ratio of two random variables (and the denominator dgrees of freedom $\leq 2$) as the following formula
$$E[X/Y]=\frac{E[X]}{E[Y]} + \frac{var[Y]E[X]}{E[X]^3}$$
and there are similar formulas for the variance as well.
And by comparing the results of this formula and the numerical results, I found that they are almost the same.

I would like to know why it is mentioned in many places (e.g. Hand-book on STATISTICAL DISTRIBUTIONS for experimentalists, page 49-50) that this distribution does not have mean or variance if the denominator degree of freedom $\leq 2$ given that it can be evaluated by the way I mentioned above ??

Comment: Hi and welcome! Add a bit of references (for *in many places*), please, to help answering to you!